# chrooted Apache+MsSQL on openBSD; Could not determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: mysql, apache, database-connection, chroot, openbsd

php generates GIFs on the web server using a databases on a second server.
The page shows 20 GIFs, so there is some load for a short time (multiple connections)

---

Some GIFs are loaded but some are not, in `/var/www/logs/error_log`

```
[Mon Feb 23 10:05:56 2009] [error] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 in /htdocs/.../myImage.php on line 4
[Mon Feb 23 10:05:56 2009] [error] PHP Fatal error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 in /htdocs/.../myImage.php on line 4
```

---

in `/var/www/logs/error_log` on the MySQL server I found:

```
[alert] httpd: Could not determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

---

Rebooting the MySQL server "resolves" the problem ... for a few days.

The 2 servers are virtual machines running OpenBSD, chroot'ed Apache and MySQL + phpMyAdmin.
unfortunately in diferent versions (OpenBSD 4.2(web) and 3.9(mysql))

my knowledge in  `/var/www/conf/httpd.conf` and `my.cnf`(didn't found it) is very limited.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Your setup and problem is not crystal clear. Why an httpd error on the MySQL server? Is httpd on the MySQL server somehow involved in this? What is your name resolution setup, and your network setup? Both machines on the same network segment? Using DNS or hosts file, or using IP Addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting resolv.conf inside chroot? Such as:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/etc/ && cp -p /etc/resolv.conf /var/www/etc/
```

You may also wish to do the same for /etc/localtime if you find your web server time is off from your time zone.

Note:

- do not use a sym link because it won't work through chroot
- do not use a hard link because modifying file in chroot would modify file in /etc!

Answer (score 1):

The "Could not determine the server's fully qualified domain name" error can be ignored, that's an internal apache thing.

Per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28359 this sounds like either a slow network, or an overloaded mysql that can't respond to connections fast enough.

Given that rebooting fixes the issue, I'm going to guess that you've got a slow resource leak. Probably something like expensive queries left running on mysql. You should be able to verify this by tracking system load over time.